# AspectJ - NullPointerException when building and compiling project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aspectj, ajdt

**Edit: I fixed this by starting an entirely new workspace and creating new projects. Everything compiles and builds now. I can't answer my own questions yet, so I'll  just put this here! I'm not deleting this post since it might be useful to others.**

I had to reinstall Eclipse from scratch. I decided to go with the newest version. I also installed the AspectJ plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace since my project uses AspectJ. Now, I have done this a few times before and I usually get issues with AspectJ. After cleaning and rebuilding and readding the projects a few times the build errors usually disappear.

But now I can't get past it. Whenever I try to build my project, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.unnecessaryCast(ProblemReporter.java:7066)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CastExpression.resolveType(CastExpression.java:512)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Assignment.resolveType(Assignment.java:150)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.resolve(Expression.java:947) ... oBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Compile error: NullPointerException thrown: null
```

The build fails at that point.

I have tried using an Indigo version of Eclipse with the Indigo version of AJDT. No luck.

I have tried reverting back to a stable branch in GIT and rebuilding. Again, same error. I've tried searching online but haven't found anything.

I am able to compile the program using an ant script that uses Java 1.6 and AspectJ 1.6.

I'm not sure where to go next to solve this problem. I am also wondering if anyone has had similar issues.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of AJDT?  Also, is this a maven project?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg The Juno version, 2.2.1.e42x-RELEASE-20120921-1400. It's not a maven project.

Comment: This looks like an AspectJ compiler bug and it may only be appearing during an incremental compile.  If you ever see this bug (or anything similar), then raise a bugzilla here: http://bugs.eclipse.org

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Will do next time I encounter something like this! Thanks.